# python pandas | index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

| volume | price | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 3 | 2021-09-29 04:00:00-04:00 |
| 300 | 2 | 2021-09-29 04:30:00-04:00 |
| 700 | 5 | 2021-09-29 05:30:00-04:00 |
| 500 | 9 | 2021-09-29 06:00:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 22 | 2021-09-29 06:30:00-04:00 |
| 400 | 29 | 2021-09-29 07:00:00-04:00 |

kindly help on the below 2 questions

1. return the datetime where volume is the max
2. return the index number where volume is the max

Comment: Is this homework?  It is unethical to have us do your homework for you.  What have you tried already?

Comment: Lol  i wish  i am still in school. but no this is not my home work , is probably the last piece of code for my side project for pulling data from stock market

Comment: Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), as well as [ask]. Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pandas `idmax` function is the one you want.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
[100,   3,  '2021-09-29 04:00:00-04:00'],
[300,   2,  '2021-09-29 04:30:00-04:00'],
[700,   5,  '2021-09-29 05:30:00-04:00'],
[500,   9,  '2021-09-29 06:00:00-04:00'],
[900,   22, '2021-09-29 06:30:00-04:00'],
[400,   29, '2021-09-29 07:00:00-04:00']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["volume","price","datetime"])
i = df["volume"].idxmax()
print(df.iloc[i])
```

Output:

```
volume                            900
price                              22
datetime    2021-09-29 06:30:00-04:00
Name: 4, dtype: object
```